# Increamenting odd values using while loop shows wrong required values

Tags: java

Why the attached code gives me this out put :

```
3 , 5 , 7 , 9
```

it should show the even values only

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    int i = 1;
    
    while ( i < 10 ){
        if ((i++)%2 == 0){
            System.out.println(i);
          
        }
    }}
```

Comment: You want to increment `i` after printing the value: `if(i%2 == 0){System.out.println(i++);}`

Comment: You are checking the condition with i and then print i+1 because of post-increment.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing `i++` inside the if. The post increment there means that the value evaluated in the condition is pre-increment but when you reach the print statement, it has been incremented. Try incrementing after the if.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
int i = 1;

while ( i < 10 ){
    if ((++i)%2 == 0){
        System.out.println(i);
      
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The evaluation is done prior to the increment.
- the printing is done after the increment.

```
int i = 1;

while ( i < 10 ){
    if ((i++)%2 == 0)  {        // i evaluated true while "even" before increment
        System.out.println(i);  // printing post increment i 
    }
}
```

To correct this, simply move the autoincrement to the left of `i`.